# Find the Pattern/Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

(1+2)

(1+2)(4+2)

(1+2)(4+2)(7+2)

(1+2)(4+2)(7+2)(10+2)

I can see that each term in the sequence is multiplied by an additional term that is 3 greater than the previous 2 terms.

How can I represent this as a sequence? (e.g. a_n= f(n) )

Comment: What have you tried

Comment: I have searched some stuff, and I found that it is common to use a product, but I am trying to use something simpler since this a_n is part of a taylor expansion

Comment: you can use factorial notation

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=\Pi_{k=0}^{n} (1+2)\cdot (4+2) \cdot (7+2) \cdot \cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot ((3k+1)+2) $$